# Как вставить в сайт документы формата docx, pdf, txt?

Tags: javascript, html

Как вставить в сайт документы формата docx, pdf, txt ?
Я загружаю документы в этом формате на свой сайт и затем хочу их просмотреть или вложить например в статью. Но как сделать чтобы они отображались на сайте?

Пробовал использовать docs.google.com но ОНО тормозит постоянно, то подскажите документ то нет. Подскажите что нибудь.

Код использования docs.google.com

```
<? php

$filesrc_url = "https://site.ru/lk/user_files/f161 1.txt";

echo '
<iframe 
class="frame_view" 
id="frame" 
src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='.$filesrc_url.'&embedded=true" width="100%" 
height="800" 
allowfullscreen 
webkitallowfullscreen>
</iframe>';

?>
```

Comment: Если вы правильно вставляете файлы из Google Drive то проблем быть не должно. Как именно вы это делали?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, вот, в вопросе написал свой код. 
Еще плохо что в docs.google нет кнопки пичать и скачать :(

Comment: Можете воспользоваться `https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=` он принимает все microsoft office. PDF могут нативно открывать большая часть браузеров. txt откроет любой браузер.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin view.officeapps не откривает pdf и txt файлы

Comment: Прочтите внимательно, как я и сказал, PDF большинство браузеров открывают и сами, поддржка txt есть у всех браузеров. Просто передавайте в iframe файл как plain/text